# Embedded PHP MySQL delete command breaks with alpha and numeric values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL command that is run within my PHP page that deletes records based on PHP parameters.  This works excellent when the EmpNumber is a number.  When this value contains a letter and a number I get the following error: Unknown column 'RR1' in 'where clause'

I've tried to substitute " for ' and that just makes the issue worse by throwing syntax errors.

```
  $WA_deleteSql = "DELETE FROM `" . $WA_table . "` WHERE EmpNumber=" . $ParamID_WADAHTG_TechQual;
```

Comment: `WHERE EmpNumber='".$ParamID_WADAHTG_TechQual."'";` give that a whirl.

Comment: can you place single quotes between "%paramId_wadaht_something"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clarifying what others failed to. If you have a letter in your string it's no longer an integer. Integers don't need to be wrapped in quotes but strings do. That is why you're getting the error. It can be avoided by adding the single quotes as others have shown in their examples:

```
$WA_deleteSql = "DELETE FROM `" . $WA_table . "` WHERE EmpNumber='$ParamID_WADAHTG_TechQual'";
```

**EDIT**

To further clarify, the field type in your table makes no difference whatsoever. You can just as easily omit the quotes on a varchar field as long as the data being passed into it (or pulled from it) is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$WA_deleteSql = "DELETE FROM `$WA_table` WHERE EmpNumber='$ParamID_WADAHTG_TechQual'";
```

We don't know what type your field is, but using single quotes is safe for both numbers and strings, while having no quotes will only work with numbers.

Comment: Is that why you downvoted me? It doesn't matter what type his field is, if there are letters it's not interger. What matters is how the data is passed, ie, with oor without the quotes.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, your post has no downvotes, but I will if you don't remove yours.